# Follow nth anchor|href via javascript

Tags: javascript, href

I'm trying embed a PDF into a page I maintain. The problem: The source filename changes every week and can not be guessed (randomNumber.pdf). So that's a dead end.

My next approach was the link on the main source site. It looks like following:

http://www.example.com/index.php?menuid=44&downloadid=190&reporeid=65

Unfortunately the "downloadid" is not strictly ongoing.

But a look into the sourcecode of that website reveales that the href I need is ALWAYS the 20th href on that site.

**Is there a way to open the 20th href via javascript?**

I wasn't able to find something useful or figure it out by myself - thanks to everybody who is trying to help!

Comment: On client-side JavaScript the answer is no because you can't access the external site using JS (unless the site has explicitly allowed it, which is very unlikely.)

Comment: You could try doing it via:
 document.getElementsByTagName("a")   Then choose the 20th Value out of the array, not beautiful, but should be working

Comment: It seems like my answer maybe was not what you wanted. Can you please explain in a little more detail what the problem might be/what you are trying to achieve? Do you want to crawl the main page to get the link and than include it to another page or what is it? :)

Comment: Hi, I want to crawl a external page (not administrated by me) for the href-information. Then embed it into my page.

Usually I would use an PDF widget or normal iFrame or something like that. But I can't guess the downloadid or the prefix of the PDF-file and it's changing every week. (It's a cafeteria menu)

Comment: Ahhh, the problem is that there seems to be no option to crawl foreign webpages with clientside JS. If you can us serverside js, you could try crawling the website with node.js and some module, take a look at this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-crawler Other way could be having a php file which returns the links/elements as an array. You can call this file via Ajax and work with it in your Javascript. A third way could be using an Userscript. This seems not to be applicable in your case, so forget about it ;)

Comment: This link actually is quiete funny, if you change 1 letter or number in the random string in front of everything, it just reverses back to normal. This might help you, maybe...

Comment: @AndersAnderson
Yes, I discovered that funny behavior as well. Unfortunately every week the 5 letter string is completely random. And if you change more than 1 letter the link is dead. I can't anticipate the combination for next week and later.

Thank you so much for helping.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my Comment in answer form:

I just get the Array of a elements and then take the 19th out of it.
When having it i use .click() on it to use it.

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

links[19].click();
```

```html
<a href ="www.google.com">1</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">2</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">3</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">4</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">5</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">6</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">7</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">8</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">9</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">10</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">11</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">12</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">13</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">14</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">15</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">16</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">17</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">18</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">19</a>
<a href ="http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp">20</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">21</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">22</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">23</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">24</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">25</a>
<a href ="www.google.com">26</a>
```

Have fun :)

Comment: Whoever downvoted that answer might explain it, so i can improve/change/delete it. By now, i don't see any reason to do anything of the above mentioned...

Comment: Not my downvote, but based on the question it's pretty obvious that the OP doesn't have edit access to the page that contains the links. Otherwise he would already know the correct link and he wouldn't have to "count" them.

Comment: Jepp that seems to be a good reason. Maybe i should ask op what he meant with his question. Thanks @Juhana :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, I promise ;)

Looks promising, but will that work for an external webpage as well? Can I create an document object with a external website?

To be more specific:
I want to access the link (it's an cafeteria menu) in the middle of this (german) site http://www.tremmel-catering.de/tremmel-tremmel-casino-landshut/
"Die aktuelle Speisekarte (pdf)"

Comment: Ahhh, the problem is that there seems to be no option to crawl foreign webpages with clientside JS. If you can us serverside js, you could try crawling the website with node.js and some module, take a look at this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-crawler